# Empirical Distribution converges to the distribution in $L^1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables with distribution $F$. Then, for each $x \in R$, do the random variables

$$
F_n(x):=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{[X_k \le x]} 
$$

converges to $F(x)$ in $L^1$? By this I mean, $\mathbb{E}[|F_n-F|] \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. I could prove that it converges $\mathbb{P}-$a.e via the law of large numbers, but I can't see how to prove the convergence in mean, in fact, I do not know if does.

Comment: Hint: Show that $(F_n(x))_{n\geqslant 1}$ is uniformly integrable.

Comment: Or use the Bounded Convergence Theorem; after all, $|F_n(x)-F(x)|\le 1$ for all $n$ and all sample points.  It's worth noting that Stefan's advice is quite general, in that $L^1$ convergence always holds in the usual Strong Law of Large Numbers, whether the summands are bounded or not.